# Any advantage of using drush remote site aliases compared with Ansible

Tags: drush

I like to use [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com), when I'm automating work on a remote server. Its agentless nature allows me to run Drush commands on those server very easily. When there are multiple sites, I can set up local aliases on a remote server and [use them](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) when running commands.

So my question is: Is there any reason, why I should run ansible playbook locally and run drush commands using remote site aliases?